# Proving the Existence of a lift

Tags: category-theory

Let $F:C\to Set$ be a functor. Let $\int F$ be the category of elements. Let $\prod:\int F\to C$ be the canonical forgetful functor. Then for any morphism $f:c\to d$ and any object $(c,x)$ in the fiber of $c$, there is a unique lift of the morphism $f$ to a morphism in $\int F$ with domain $(c,x)$ that projects along $\prod$ to $f$.

My question is how do I prove the existence of a lift? Would I construct it or define it? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: Yes, you construct it. Consider the definition of $\int F$ and what a morphism lifting $f$ would have to do to $x$.

Comment: Could it be the map $(f,g)$ where $g$ is a map from $x$ to $Ffx$?

Comment: That seems like a slightly mistaken description of a map in $\int F$. Recall that a map $(c,x)\to (c',y)$ is given by a map $f:c\to c'$ *such that* $Ff(x)=y$. There's no notion of a "map from $x$ to $Ffx$" available a priori.

Comment: You are right. We have a map $f:c\to d$ and we have an object $(c,x)$. So, can't we define a map $g:(c,x)\to (d, Ffx)$ which is given by the map $f$? Are we looking for an explicit formula?

Comment: Yes, $g$ is the map you want, and you have just given an explicit formula for it.

Comment: How is that explicit?

Comment: How is it not? You can't possibly get more explicit than identifying a morphism of a category via a formula which is an instantiation of the *definition* of morphisms of that category.

Comment: Also, uniqueness must follow since any other morphism must be defined in a similar fashion. Okay, thank you for leading me to the answer.

Comment: Anytime. You might consider writing up your own answer so that this doesn't appear unfinished.

Comment: I am learning category theory for fun.